Qual a diferença entre siga-me e segue-me?

“Se alguém me quer seguir, renuncie a si mesmo, tome sua cruz cada dia, e segue-me” (Lucas 9, 23).


Qual tradução da Bíblia?

Eu adaptei uma versão qualquer por não encontrar em nenhuma tradução a frase na forma como eu me lembrava ter visto. Porém a passagem que eu estava buscando fica em Marcos e não em Lucas.

"E Jesus, olhando para ele, o amou e lhe disse: Falta-te uma coisa: vai, vende tudo quanto tens, e dá-o aos pobres, e terás um tesouro no céu; e vem, segue-me." (SUD)

o verbo seguir

segue-me é o imperativo afirmativo, a 2.ª pessoa do singular (tu) do presente. No imperativo negativo há "s" na segunda pessoa.

siga-me seria o imperativo afirmativo, na 3.ª pessoa do singular (você)


A confusão feita entre as pessoas (segunda ou terceira) se explica pelo seguinte:

Dúvidas no uso do imperativo
O principal erro na utilização do
imperativo está relacionado com a confusão existente entre a 2.ª
pessoa do discurso (tu) e a 3.ª pessoa do discurso (você). A maioria
dos brasileiros utiliza a 3.ª pessoa do discurso, mas utiliza o
imperativo na 2.ª pessoa do discurso, havendo assim falta de
uniformidade e coesão.

verbos no imperativo
Isso quer dizer que na fala normal, o brasileiro usa diferentes pessoas no afirmativo e imperativo. Fica incoerente do ponto de vista da gramática.

O uso do imperativo da segunda pessoa é meio informal. O que melhor soa ao ouvi é o imperativo da terceira pessoa e é mais formal.

@Schilive Fica óbvio isso pela minha resposta que explica a confusão para alguns falantes brasileiros.

É que na minha leitura, a resposta dá a entender que o uso do imperativo da terceira pessoa não é normal, mas não é o caso na minha experiência.

@Schilive Minha resposta não diz:  o uso do imperativo da terceira pessoa não é normal, Explica a confusão entre a segunda e terceira pessoa.

A diferença é a forma de tratamento (tu vs 3ª pessoa). O que é estranho nesse trecho é que a segunda pessoa nunca seria usada nesta situação. Mesmo dirigido a um grupo de pessoas que trataríamos por tu, diríamos:

Se alguém quiser, que (essa pessoa) me diga/diga-me.
Quem quiser, que (essa pessoa) me diga/diga-me.

Nunca diz-me (numa frase imperativa).
